# Trying to convert a date field, it leads to errors while conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying the below query and keep getting the error for ResCreation date, I used CAST thinking that Rescreation date might have some bad fields. Not sure what field is wrong.

```
SELECT TOP(5) 
    [PCode]
    ,[ADate]
    ,[DDate]
    ,[ResCreationDate]
    ,[CancelDate]
FROM 
    [ResDomain] 
WHERE
    CAST(ResCreationDate AS DATE) >= '2018-01-01'
```

The error that I am getting:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

That's the sample data output:

```
PCode   ADate                DDate              ResCreationDate    CancelDate
FL7112  2018-07-30 00:00:00 2018-08-03 00:00:00 2018-05-29 16:34:30 2018-07-25 12:35:00
MT2091  2018-05-03 00:00:00 2018-05-04 00:00:00 2018-05-02 21:58:27 NULL
2075    2018-03-31 00:00:00 2018-04-01 00:00:00 2018-04-01 00:18:40 NULL
2012    2018-07-07 00:00:00 2018-07-08 00:00:00 2018-06-16 17:38:29 2018-06-30 03:20:00
2587    2018-06-30 00:00:00 2018-07-01 00:00:00 2018-06-30 11:18:10 NULL
```

Not sure if I should try another datatype, I used '2018-01-01 00:00:00' too in the `where` clause, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try_cast()`:

```
SELECT  TOP (5) [PCode], [ADate], [DDate], [ResCreationDate]
FROM [ResDomain] 
WHERE TRY_CAST(ResCreationDate as Date) >= '2018-01-01';
```

Or, better yet, find the bad data and fix it!

```
SELECT ResCreationDate
FROM ResDomain
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(Date, ResCreationDate) IS NULL;
```

Comment: I would go with the second one (find bad data and fix it). Even though the `TRY_CAST` seems like a good idea, you'll be only kicking a problem into the future. In simple words, you would be making a time bomb. I don't like time bombs.

Comment: does try_convert, convert the entire column in my table temporarily or permanently?

Comment: @Sanky . . . It is a function used in a `SELECT` query.  `SELECT` does not modify the underlying tables.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon!